# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 when use file_get_contents

Tags: php, rest

when I use file_get_contents function I get Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway in xammp/...

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$price = $_GET['price'];
$residue = $_GET['residue'];

file_get_contents("http://example.com:8080/?apikey=***********=&pid=*********&fnum=*******&tnum=$phone&p1=name&p2=price&p3=residue&v1=$name&v2=$price&v3=$residue");
```

Comment: Fix your `http://example.com:8080`, not this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failed to open stream means the target file was not located. Either the server responded with a `404 HTTP Status` or the file is missing.

Use the proper URL
Ensure your API Keys are still valid with server you're requesting to.

---

You can copy the URL to a browser and see the response from there.

Comment: Thank you
When I sent $name to the API, it was sent with a space, that's why I had this problem.

Comment: welcome. Always try some URL in your browser when PHP fails to return more detailed errors.